# puppeteer / doesn't accept any action after login

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, apify

I tried to login and do another action after login using puppeteer/node js 
it accepts login and after login the account it never does any action yet

this's my code

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  
async function log_in() {
    
   const browser =await  puppeteer.launch({
    headless:false,
    args: ['--Window-size=1929,1170','--Window-position=0,0']

    });

   

     const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({'width': 1366, 'height': 768 });   
    await page.goto('url');

    await page.click('.fancybox-item');
    await delay(1000);

 // fun for waiting 
    function delay(time) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
       setTimeout(resolve, time)
   });
}

 const UserName= '070xxxxxx';
 const Password= '222222';



 page.click('.icon-Signin');
 await delay(1000);
 
 await page.type('#loginform-username', UserName);
 await page.type('#loginform-password', Password);

 
 //Go to the next page 
 await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(), // The promise resolves after navigation has finished
  page.click('.greenBtn'), // Clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
   
]);

 await delay(5000);
 
 await page.click('#header > div > div.userMenu.mt15.mb15.fLeft > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a');
 
 await delay(5000);
 await browser.close();
 
}log_in();
```

- if anyone can review the code and know the issue to help me to fix it 
  note: I have the same issue for registration it registers successfully and after access the site it never do any action

Comment: The problem might be that `page.waitForNavigation()` never happens to the promise doesn't resolve. Try only the `page.click('.greenBtn')`

Comment: I try to remove it, and it's passed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is few points in your code may cause issues:

1. Try to investigate how does login happen. `page.waitForNavigation()` method waits for form submit or URL change using History API. In case no navigation actually performed you could use [`page.waitForSelector`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options) or [`page.waitForXPath`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pagewaitforxpathxpath-options) method to wait for appear of any specific element. Otherwise try to use `page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })`
2. Using timeouts to wait for results of async task is not a good practice. You may face network slow down at least. So script will probably out of `await delay(...);` before expected action done. I recommend you to wait with `page.waitFor*` for appear of the login popup(of anything else) after click on `.fancybox-item`.
3. You're not waiting actually for result of `page.click('.icon-Signin');`. Click event handler may take more time in some conditions. Don't forget about `await`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not rely to such as delay or setTimeout function if you're not waiting a real timer. If you're only need some time to wait for a navigation or any UI changes, `page.waitFor` and `page.waitForSelector`, or `page.waitForNavigation` is enough.
2. Use `page.waifForNavigation` BEFORE the navigation event occur. This means the function start listening to the page events and resolve the promise if the navigation start. This mistake is usually happen, as people put `page.waitForNavigation` after the navigation event itself happen.

So here the code, i've edit it for you. And tell me if this work perfectly or not.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const UserName= '070xxxxxx'
const Password= '222222'


const log_in = async () => {

    // fun for waiting
    function delay(time) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            setTimeout(resolve, time)
        })
    }

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless:false,
        args: ['--Window-size=1929,1170','--Window-position=0,0']
    })

    const page = (await browser.pages())[0]
    page.setViewport({'width': 1366, 'height': 768 })
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)

    await page.goto('url', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'})

    // Is line below start navigation event? If so, use the commented lines below it
    await page.click('.fancybox-item')
    // const clickFancy = await Promise.all([
        // page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'}), // <= change it to load or networkidle0 if you like
        // page.click('.fancybox-item')
    // ])

    // await delay(1000) // => DO NOT USE THIS IF YOU'RE NOT SURELY WAITING FOR ANY TIMER

    // Is line below fire a navigation event? If so, use the commented lines below it
    page.click('.icon-Signin')
    // const clickLogin = await Promise.all([
        // page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'}), // <= change it to load or networkidle0 if you like
        // page.click('.icon-Signin')
    // ])

    // await delay(1000) // => DO NOT USE THIS IF YOU'RE NOT SURELY WAITING FOR ANY TIMER

    await page.type('#loginform-username', UserName)
    await page.type('#loginform-password', Password)

    //Go to the next page
    const nextPage = await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation('domcontentloaded'), // The promise resolves after navigation has finished
        page.click('.greenBtn') // Clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
    ])

    // await delay(5000) => DO NOT USE THIS IF YOU'RE NOT SURELY WAITING FOR ANY TIMER

    // Is line below fire a navigation event? If so, use the commented lines below it
    await page.click('#header > div > div.userMenu.mt15.mb15.fLeft > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a')
    // const clickFancy = await Promise.all([
        // page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'}), // <= change it to load or networkidle0 if you like
        // await page.click('#header > div > div.userMenu.mt15.mb15.fLeft > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a')
    // ])

    // await delay(5000) => DO NOT USE THIS IF YOU'RE NOT SURELY WAITING FOR ANY TIMER
    await browser.close()
}

log_in()
```